# Numpy Array - Drop Duplicates

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to remove duplicate elements from a numpy array.

```
Eg:
a = np.array([[0.03,0.32],[0.09,0.26],[0.03,0.32]])
a = np.unique(a,axis=0)
```

This is perfectly working.
But the problem is this code is a part of a function. And I run the function say 10 times. At any one run the system gets hanged at exactly this line.
I notice that array would be of max 3500 size and each element (inner array) would be of length 60.
Why is this happening or any other efficient way?

Comment: `np.unique(np.random.random((3500, 60)), axis=0)` works perfectly fine. Can you provide some data which **reproduces your problem**?

Comment: Do you really need python3 AND python2 compatible code? If not, remove the wrong one and add the "pure" python tag: [tag:python]

Answer (score 3):

There's quite a few issues with what you're doing.

**First, observe that `np.unique` does not work well for floating point arithmetic, and will not *in general* filter out "unique" arrays of floats:**

```
In [16]: a = np.array([[2.1*3, .123], [6.3, 2.05*.06]])

In [17]: a
Out[17]: 
array([[6.3  , 0.123],
       [6.3  , 0.123]])

In [18]: np.unique(a, axis=0)
Out[18]: 
array([[6.3  , 0.123],
       [6.3  , 0.123]])
```

Note that the duplicates are still in the result after calling `np.unique`. The reason for this is because `np.unique` is comparing on *equality* meaning, that the floats must match bit for bit. However, floating point arithmetic is not exact, so you are not guaranteed to filter out duplicates correctly.

**Secondly, in terms of performance, you can do better than `np.unique` with a hashable type.** `np.unique` will always run in O(n log n) since it does a sort. You can verify this in the source code:

```
if optional_indices:
    perm = ar.argsort(kind='mergesort' if return_index else 'quicksort')
    aux = ar[perm]
else:
    ar.sort()
    aux = ar
```

So, regardless of how the conditional evaluates, a sort is performed over `ar` (which is the input array, see here for more detail: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.15.0/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py#L277). The reason for this is because `np.unique` supports a rich set of functionality (like getting the indices of dups, returning the count of dups, etc).

You don't have to sort to get unique elements. If you beat your type into a hashable type (like `tuple`), then you can filter out duplicates in O(n), linear time. Here's an example:

```
In [37]: b
Out[37]: 
[(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
 (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
 (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
 (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
 (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
 (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
 (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
 (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
 (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
 (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)]

In [39]: np.unique(b, axis=0)
Out[39]: array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])

In [40]: set(b)
Out[40]: {(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)}

In [41]: %timeit np.unique(b, axis=0)
21.9 µs ± 132 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [42]: %timeit set(b)
627 ns ± 5.09 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

So, as you can see, just using the built-in `set` runs about 30x faster than `np.unique`. Please note this will not work correctly for arrays of floats, but I just wanted to show that `np.unique` is not particularly performant from an algorithmic perspective.

**Lastly, 3500x60 is not really that big. You can loop through that pretty easily, even with a subpar algorithm, and it should not hang on any modern hardware.** It should run pretty fast:

```
In [43]: np.random.seed(0)

In [46]: x = np.random.random((3500, 60))

In [49]: %timeit np.unique(x, axis=0)
2.57 ms ± 17.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

So it takes 2.57 millisecond on my MacBook Pro, which isn't exactly a powerhouse in terms of hardware (2.3 GHz i5, 8GB of RAM). **Make sure you're profiling your code, and make sure that the line in this question is *actually* the trouble line.**

HTH.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed explanation. It really helped. I understand 3500*60 is not that big that is why it got me worried. So now for float how can we achieve it better than using np.unique